# Why the square root canceled here?

Tags: calculus

My problem in the following example

[image]

I want to know why the square root canceled in the formula of distance

Comment: $\sqrt{r}$ is a monotonous function. If you find the minimum of $r$ within a set (the constraint) then its $\sqrt{}$ will be minimum, as well, within that set.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a strictly increasing function $f$ to another function $g$, then $f(g)$ has the same extrema as $g$ over the domain considered.

In this case, $f(w) = w^2$.